# Forgetting name of influential paper on evolution applied to corporations

Tags: reference-request, theory

There is a paper that I would like to cite because I remember what it said except that I am forgetting who wrote it and what its title was. Basically people were skeptical that corporations could always know exactly what consumer's preferences were and how they could be met. This guy published a paper arguing that they didn't even have to know what they had to do to be successful, by an application of evolutionary theory, because the more successful businesses would naturally perpetuate and multiply themselves while the other businesses shut down.

Comment: Do you perhaps remember which century this paper was written it?

Comment: @Giskard Yes almost certainly the 20th. Also I did not actually read the paper myself, it was mentioned in an encyclopedia or something of the sort.

Comment: Are you sure this was a scientific paper?

Comment: @Giskard Not really. Unfortunately, if you don't recognize it from my cursory description, you probably don't know what it is. It may not be that famous, I just remember reading that it changed how people thought about a supposed market failure or something like that. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @Giskard I am quite sure it was a paper published in an economic journal. The fundamental idea behind it wasn't very empirical or mathematical but neither was say Coase's paper on externalities.

Comment: Alright, hope someone will recognize it from this. My confusion arises because if you know the "invisible hand" theory as well as natural selection, their combination is rather intuitive. (Though the combined model inherits all weaknesses of the invisible hand.)

Comment: This sounds a little bit like Schumpeter's creative destruction.

Comment: @Athaeneus What I'm referring to is far more anodyne. The concept is simply that the corporations with the wrong ideas won't earn money and will die out leaving the ones that happened to have the correct ideas. Corporations don't need to reliably be able to figure out the correct ideas in order for corporations to reliably have the correct ideas

Comment: @Athaeneus And it was published specifically in response to skepticism about whether corporations could really know what people want and act rationally